# C++ Flaten lists inside structs inside map

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, struct

I'm trying to find occurrences of an element in lists inside structs contained in am map. The context is that I'm trying to implement a must-join for a cache analysis assignment.
I tried to illustrate the constellation:

[image: Cache analysis - Must join]

I've barely have basic knowledge in c, so I'm struggling to find the best way to access the elements of all lists residing in the `struct Entry` contained in the `map<unsigned int, Entry> Associativity`. Here is what I've tried so far:

```c
// Only entries below this comment are needed for the exercise.

  /**
   * @brief Containing all Abstract Cache Tags.
   *        Key of the list has no Meaning.
   *
   */
  struct Entry {
    std::list<unsigned int> Blocks;
  };

  /**
   * @brief Cache Set, Key is the Age of the Entries.
   *
   */
  struct Set {
    // uInt in this map is the Age.
    std::map<unsigned int, Entry> Associativity;
  };

  /**
   * @brief Cache Sets, key is the Set number [0-15], derived from Address.
   *
   */
  std::map<unsigned int, Set> Sets;

 /**
   * @brief Executes an Must LRU Join on the AbstractCacheState
   *
   * @param In, AbstractState that gets joined into the State.
   */
  void mustJoin(AbstractState In) {
  /**
     *  TODO: Fill this function with an LRU must Join.
     * For this you need to use Sets. Associativity and Blocks.
     */

    // Loop through all 16 sets
    for (int Index = 0; Index < 16; Index++) {

      // create a temporary set of associativity
      struct Set temp_set;
      struct Set current_set = Sets[Index];
      struct Set incoming_set = In.Sets[Index];

      // loop through all Ages
      for (auto associativity_map : current_set.Associativity) {

        auto current_associativity_age = associativity_map.first;
        std::list<unsigned int> current_associativity_blocklist =
            associativity_map.second.Blocks;
        // for every element of associativity_block_list
        for (auto block : current_associativity_blocklist) {
          // look through ALL incoming_set.Associativities.Entry.Blocklists for
          // occurrences
          for (auto incoming_associativity : incoming_set.Associativity) {
            auto age = incoming_associativity.first;
            struct Entry entry = incoming_associativity.second;

            auto ret =
                std::find(entry.Blocks.begin(), entry.Blocks.end(), block);
            if (ret != entry.Blocks.end()) {

              // take the maximum age
              auto new_age = std::max(current_associativity_age, age);

              // create a new entry at the maximum age and
              std::list<unsigned int> new_block_list;
              new_block_list.push_back((unsigned int) *ret);
              struct Entry new_entry = {new_block_list};

              // add it to temporary set
              temp_set.Associativity.insert(
                  std::pair<unsigned int, struct Entry>(new_age, new_entry));
            }
          }
        }
        // print_block_list(associativity_age, associativity_block_list);

        Sets[Index] = temp_set;
      }
    }
  }
```

After googling for while I found that there are stream functions like `transform` and `accumulate`. Can I implement this efficiently with those (or similar) functions?

Comment: There are very few things in C++ that have merely a button somewhere that only needs to be pushed, in order for them to happen. In nearly all of the cases all the work must be done by yourself. Basic algorithms, like `std::transform` and `std::accumulate` are just elementary basic blocks. Which C++ textbook are you using to learn this, the most complicated and the hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today? C++ is just too complex to be learned by doing only Google searches, or watching random Youtube videos, or reading someone's stream of consciousness, on their blog.

Comment: I understand perfectly; I don't know why my professor assumed, it'll be "doable" even with no prior knowledge of the C programming language. I have some programming knowledge from other areas and I know how to search for answers on the web. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) were my primary sources of information. But none of the examples enlighten me on how to adapt `std::transform` and `std:accumulate` to my problem. So I agree, I can't learn the intricacy of C++ just by googling.

Comment: `transform` is for modifying something. `accumulate` is for adding or combining something. None of them are for merely iterating over something without modifying it. That would be `std::for_each`. But, again, this is just a basic building block. This is just for iterating over a single container. If a value is another container, it's up to you to iterate over it too. `std::for_each` replacing just a single `for` loop. To replace nested `for` loop you'll also have to use nester `std::for_each`s, too. Again: there are very few magic buttons in C++ that will do everything for you.