# Implement a may-join for a cache analysis

Tags: c++, caching, memory, data-structures, lru

[image]I came across this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72377505/c-flaten-lists-inside-structs-inside-map) where the fellow user was trying to implement a LRU cache with must join. As I am a beginner in C++ I am struggling to implement and check how a may-join might work for a LRU cache. The resources for learning about this topic is very limited and I would be grateful if someone could help me out with this as it's hard to learn and code whilst having a full time job. Any help would be appreciated.

I understood the must join part but currently struggling with may join for over 2 months.

The code is present in the link above and I haven't copied the code here as it might be a plagiarism from my part. Kindly help with the code or refer to some good materials. Thank you

[image]

This link might help for a deep understanding. https://www.rw.cdl.uni-saarland.de/people/reineke/private/talks/cachesInWCETAnalysis.pdf

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're having problems with and what part of the code is not working for you. Also see *[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)*

Comment: The code in the link is for a must-join and I am trying to implement a may-join. I am extremely new to C++ and I am unable to reproduce the code for a may-join.

Comment: I see. Well you need to edit your post and include your current code, explain what it's trying to do, what behavior your expecting, and the problem you're having along with what incorrect behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain, or point us to a reference that explains, the difference between must join and may join.

Comment: @JimMischel I have added an image. The resources for this topic are very limited and that is one of the reason why I wanted to know about this specific topic.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I have already coded for the same for must analysis in python but as I am trying to learn and implement cache concepts in C++. I do not know advanced C++ and the code which I gave link to was my basis of understanding of implementation in C++.

Comment: I suppose part of the problem is that you're new to programming in general. C++ doesn't have "cache concepts". You have to program caches yourself. That's not really advanced C++, but it is advanced Computer Science. But since you've got the book and a Python implementation, it sounds like you've mastered the CompSci part.

Comment: @Dein_coder Please tell me what book that's from. I want to be sure never to buy or attempt to read that book. The picture and description you posted are not at all helpful. I've tried to make sense of it three different times now, and it's all gibberish. Perhaps I need coffee.

Comment: @JimMischel. Think link might be helpful for you. https://www.rw.cdl.uni-saarland.de/people/reineke/private/talks/cachesInWCETAnalysis.pdf

Comment: If your goal is to implement this *may-join* approach then you should do it in a language you are comfortable with and have knowledge of. If your goal is to learn C++ then you should learn C++ without the complexity of something you can't associate with the constructs of C++. Either way your request as it stands now seems to be way outside the scope of StackOverflow.